# Generating random numbers to put in an array, if number is a duplicate draw then reroll. Boolean check is "sometimes" working

Tags: java, arrays, random, boolean

Edit: Uh well now that I pasted code into here and looked at it.. I have 2 .. "duplicate methods" .. Eclipse for some god awful reason hid the first "boolean checkforDupes()" from me. It seems to be fixed now, still poking it to make sure, should I just like.. delete the post or something?

I have a class assignment, which I've done essentially everything for, but I'm having issues with generating some random numbers to put into an array, and if they number has already been "drawn" then the number is re-generated so that there are no duplicates.

I've looked through several articles and have seen various ways to accomplish what I'm trying to do, but I'm really just trying to locate the flaw in my method/reasoning/etc. 
(Pulling numbers from a fully populated array randomly, or shuffling an array and picking a handful, using a Set for unique numbers etc)

Essentially the program is just supposed to generate 5 lotto numbers, player(or computer player in this case) also selects 5 numbers. Each number set is to be unique, and then you compare the Array/List/whatever and pull out matches for assumed points or notoriety.

Somewhere between my generateNumbers() and checkForDupes() methods my logic has failed me and I've been stumped for a few hours. Sometimes the generator works and recognizes that it has rolled a duplicate and will reroll, but other times it will say reroll the first number but numbers 3 & 4 are duplicates which it ignores.

Any insight into this would be much appreciated.

```
package lottery;
import java.util.*;

public class Lottery {

    final int chance = 5; //holds the number of lottery numbers to be picked
    private int lotteryNumbers[] = new int[chance]; //array to hold the lottery numbers
    private int playerNumbers[] = new int[chance]; //array to hold player's numbers
    //Maybe rewrite with a Set instead of Array.
    //Or generate random numbers and put them in array and "draw" lotto numbers from the array. Well now that I'm looking at my post, this comment is more of my I give up, next step stuff !


    public Lottery(){
        generateNumbers(lotteryNumbers);
        System.out.println("Lottery numbers");
        generateNumbers(playerNumbers);
        System.out.println("Player numbers");
    }

    public String returnDate(){
        Date date = new Date();
        // display time and date using toString()
        return date.toString();
    }

    public int[] getLotteryNumbers() {
        return lotteryNumbers;
    }

    public int[] getPlayerNumbers() {
        return playerNumbers;
    }

    private int[] generateNumbers(int[] numbers){
        int check;//variable to pass for checking dupes
        int count = 0;
        Boolean DoIt=null;

        Random rng = new Random(); //Used to pick lottery numbers

        while (count<chance)
        {

                check = rng.nextInt(5)+1;//assigns random number to check
                DoIt = checkforDupes(check, numbers);//passes check and the array to be checked for dupes
            if (DoIt == true)   //to execute if dupe checker says its ok
            {
                numbers[count] = check;
                System.out.print(numbers[count]+" in ["+count+"], ");
                count++;
            }
            else    //supposed to restart the loop without incrementing for a new number if dupe
            {
                System.out.println(" Dupe rerolling  "+check+" ["+count+"], ");
            }               

        }
        return numbers;
    }

    private boolean checkforDupes(int check, int[] array){
        //pass in the generated variable and the array, check array if duplicates then return true or false to add the number
        for(int i=0; i<chance; i++)
            if (check == array[i])
                return false;
            else 
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    private Boolean checkForDupes(int check, int[] array){
        Boolean doIt = false;
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            if (check == array[i])
            {
                doIt = false;
                System.out.println("DON'T!"); //not printing anything to console
                break;
            }   
            else
                doIt = true;
        }
        System.out.println("Am I even being called"); //also not printing to console...
        return doIt;
    }

    public void checkMatches(int[] array1, int[] array2){

        for (int index = 0; index<array1.length; index++)
            if (array1[index] == array2[index])
                System.out.print(array1[index]+"  ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("**** Possible Matches listed above ****");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (check == array[i])
    return false;
else 
    return true;
```

This is in a for loop, so it runs once for each array element (with `i` being the index of that element).

If `check` equals this array element, you return `false`. Otherwise, you return `true`.

And it never gets to go around the loop again, because returning exits the method immediately.

Comment: I do see what you are pointing at, and it seems to have definitely been part of the issue.. but also eclipse hid that entire method from me and I was talking to it.. instead of its twin brother or whatever I thought I was. Kudos for the quick response for sure!

Comment: @AAMP31B Java uses case sensitive identifiers. `checkforDupes` and `checkForDupes` are two different methods. `boolean` and `Boolean` are two different (but related) types.

Comment: Yeah I totally see that now, on my screen eclipse entirely hid the first method. Which was what my number generator was calling while I was editing the second method. I was entirely blind to the slightly different method name and types until I scrolled through my code after submitting the post.

Answer (score 0):

Here i have implemented with c# you can convert it into java if needed. I have used dictionary for faster searching.
Here is the code, You can modify it accordingly:

```
static Dictionary<int, int> randomNoArray = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    static int[] arrayHavingManyNo= new int[] { 3, 4, 5,........... };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int randomNo = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("press 1 to generate random and insert.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 2 to display No in Array");
            if (Console.Read() == 1)
            {
                randomNo = GenerateRandom(1, 100);
                if (!checkInArray(randomNo))
                {
                    InsertInArray(Full[randomNo], Full[randomNo]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> pair in randomNoArray)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(pair.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static int GenerateRandom(int start,int end)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(new Random().Next(start, end));
    }
    static bool checkInArray(int no)
    {
        return (randomNoArray.ContainsKey(Full[no]));
    }
    static void InsertInArray(int key , int value)
    {
        randomNoArray.Add(key,value);
    }

}
```